# Jacobian of Proximal Operator is Positive Semidefinite

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, jacobian, proximal-operators

I have been reading a paper involving the following proximal operator $\hat{y}:R^{p} \to R^p$:
$$\hat{y}(v) := \text{argmin}_{\beta \in {R}^{p}} \left\{\frac{1}{2} \|v - \beta\|_2^2 + \theta \|\Sigma^{-1/2} \beta \|_1 \right\}$$
where $\theta > 0$ is a constant and $\Sigma$ is positive definite matrix. According to the paper, "by general properties of proximal operators, the Jacobian matrix is positive semi-definite." The paper refers to the book "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" by Heinz H. Bauschke and Patrick L. Combettes. However, I was unable to find such results in the book. I can prove this result when $\Sigma = I_p$ because the proximal operator has close form. It is not clear to me whether it is correct for general $\Sigma$. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the paper you are mentionning ?

Comment: This might be helqful https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3053058/168758 (also see discussion under the question

Comment: The paper I am mentionning is "The Lasso with general Gaussian designs with applications to hypothesis testing". It is on Appendix Page 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to "[A characterization of proximity operators](https://hal-centralesupelec.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01835101/)", by Gribonval and Nikolova, in particular Theorem 4 in the smooth case: an operator $f$ is a proximal operator if and only if there exists a convex function $\psi$ such that $f(y) = \nabla \psi(y)$ for all $y$.

The Jacobian of $f$ is thus the Hessian of $\psi$ which is p.s.d. by convexity of $\psi$.